Can't start system window dialog alert extend service via broadcast reciever when app is closed: taget api level 31 or above
I unable to show window alert dialog extend service from broadcast reciever. Basically my broadcast reciever is not triggering my WindowLeadsService class.
I don't know what the problem occuring here, i tried startForeground() method inside onCreate still didn't fixed
Here I'm putting my logic
WindowsLeadsService
public class WindowLeadsService extends Service {

    private WindowManager windowManager;

    private View dialogView;

    private TextView textView3;

    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "ForegroundServiceChannel";

    

    private void startForegroundService() {

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)

            .setContentTitle("Foreground Service")

            .setContentText("Service is running")

            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon)

            .build();

        

        startForeground(1, notification);

    }



    @Override

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        return START_NOT_STICKY;

    }

    

    @Override

    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        return null;

    }



    private void createNotificationChannel() {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

            NotificationChannel serviceChannel = new NotificationChannel(

                CHANNEL_ID,

                "Foreground Service Channel",

                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT

            );



            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);

            manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel);

        }

    }

    

    @Override

    public void onCreate() {

        super.onCreate();

        createNotificationChannel();

        startForegroundService();

        

        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customized_leads, null);



        textView3 = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.textview3);



        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(

                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,

                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,

                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,

                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,

                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        windowManager.addView(dialogView, params);



        TextView textView2 = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.textview2);

        TextView textView3 = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.textview3);

        TextView textView5 = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.textview5);

        TextView textView6 = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.textview6);

        TextView textView7 = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.textview7);

        TextView textView8 = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.textview8);

        ImageView imageView1 = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.imageview1);

        ImageView imageView2 = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.imageview2);

        LinearLayout linear14 = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.linear14);

        LinearLayout linear28 = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.linear28);

        

        //click listeners

        linear14.setOnClickListener(

                new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override

                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        // Handle click

                        stopSelf();

                        String phoneNumber = "tel:+917233456780";

                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(phoneNumber));

                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                        try {

                            startActivity(intent);

                        } catch (SecurityException excep) {

                            Toast.makeText(

                                            getApplicationContext(),

                                            "Something went wrong.",

                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)

                                    .show();

                        }

                    }

                });



        linear28.setOnClickListener(

                new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override

                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        // Handle click

                        stopSelf();

                    }

                });

    }



    @Override

    public void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();

        if (dialogView != null) {

            windowManager.removeView(dialogView);

        }

    }

}

BroadcastReciever
public class RebootService extends BroadcastReceiver {



    @Override

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {

           Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, WindowLeadsService.class);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

                context.startForegroundService(serviceIntent);

            } else {

                context.startService(serviceIntent);

            }

        }

     }
 }

I Found Error in logs
java.lang.RuntimeException: android.app.ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException: startForegroundService() not allowed due to mAllowStartForeground false: service 

This question is similar to: Fatal Android 12: Exception: startForegroundService() not allowed due to mAllowStartForeground false. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@rand'Chris i couldn't find any suitable solution about this problem i guess it's more darkest area of android section. Will you analysis codes & answer.!

Unfortunately I cannot. Did you look at the second answer in the link I shared? Your WindowLeadsService extends from Service and in there they state: "So from now on, (i.e) from targetSdk 31 / Android 12+, Service can be invoked only when the application is in the foreground. When the application is closed or when the application went to the background, invoking Service using startForegroundService will cause ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException. So to perform background tasks in Android 12 and above, we need to use Worker instead of Service"

@rand'Chris i looked at the link but still unable to solve this headache, i already used workers still didn't

Well, if Service is known not to work your question should be updated to show the code using workers that is not working, along with the updated error message. Otherwise you're likely to get the same type of "this is a dupe" response. This site is meant to answer questions like "How would I do  given ", not "Fix my code."

@rand'Chris well brother i will.
